# How to read and modify content of SitePages(aspx) Programatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sitepages

How to read and modify content of SitePages Programatically ?

"http://myServer/sites/SitePages/MySitePage.aspx"

i want to read and modify content of MySitePage.aspx.

Any Solution??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can access the contents (Webparts) by using the SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager method. More here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx